# Laravel Dusk test click() not working

Tags: php, testing, laravel-5, automated-tests, laravel-dusk

I'm trying to run some tests on a Laravel project but **even the most basic tests won't work**.

Configuration:

- Laravel 5.5
- Dusk for tests
- MacOS High Sierra
- PHPStorm

*I would like to test the login page.*

#### First of all, I know I have to add an attribute to the `<button>` in `resources->views->forms->user->login.blade.php`:

Source : [image: Laravel Dusk doc]

My code:

```
<div class="submit-button-container">
    <button class="button" dusk="login-button">Connexion</button>
</div>
```

#### Then I create the `LoginTest.php`file:

```
<?php

namespace Tests\Browser;

use Tests\DuskTestCase;
use Laravel\Dusk\Browser;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\DatabaseMigrations;

class LoginTest extends DuskTestCase
{
    /**
     * @throws \Exception
     * @throws \Throwable
     */
    public function testExample()
    {
        $this->browse( function (Browser $browser) {

            $browser->visit('se-connecter') //login page
                    ->click('@login-button'); //click the login button
        });
    }
}
```

#### When I run the command line `php artisan dusk` I get this error :

*no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"body [dusk="login-button"]"}*

#### MY QUESTION IS:

- How do I define a selector as shown on the error message ?

Comment: Are you sure, you are testing on the correct page/url?

Comment: Did you check a screenshot ?

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue with Dusk and Laravel 9. I found one solution in this [laracasts course](https://laracasts.com/series/browser-testing-with-laravel-dusk) I ended up with this:

```
->press('button[type="submit"]')
```

basically it selects the submit button on the page and presses it.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `->assertMissing('@login-button')` just to be sure that dusk sees that element. Maybe it could give an insight into where the problem is. Or you may not be on the same page.

Check out in the screenshots folder. 
It is not the way out but at least it will help you identify the way out.